# Darlington transistor configuration

Tags: transistors, pcb, output, darlington, biasing

Can two 2n2222a transistors output more than 1amp of current if biased properly; supposing 1.4v to 1.5v is applied to the base?

Comment: " supposing 1.4v to 1.5v is applied to the base?" Do not apply a voltage to a base. Apply a _current_.

Answer (score 12):

No.

[The maximum absolute rating for a 2N2222A is 0.6 A](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/p2n2222a-d.pdf).

A Darlington configuration increases the gain, not the current handling ability. On the contrary, a Darlington configuration often *decreases* the current handling ability because the on voltage is about 1 V instead of about 0.2 V, so the transistor hits another maximum absolute rating, the maximum power dissipation, even before it hits its maximum absolute rating for current.

Answer (score 11):

Not with a Darlington configuration.

But if you were to connect them in parallel you would effectively double the current rating. This is done in things like linear power supplies and audio amplifiers all the time. A small resistance is usually put in the emitter circuit of each of the paralleled transistors to aid in sharing the current equally between them.